# Flex component binding click handlers in application

Tags: actionscript-3, function, apache-flex, data-binding

I have created a component with 2 buttons. Each button's click function is bound to a variable. I need to swap out the default button handlers that are defined in the component with the handlers that are defined in the application.

**ZoomButtons.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    preinitialize="onPreinitialize(event)">
    <mx:script>
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Bindable] public var zoomOutHandler:Function;
        [Bindable] public var zoomInHandler:Function;

        protected function onPreinitialize(event:FlexEvent):void {
            zoomOutHandler = localZoomOutHandler;
            zoomInHandler = localZoomInHandler;
        }

        private function localZoomOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        private function localZoomInHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    </mx:script>
    <mx:Button id="zoomOut" label="-" width="20"
        toolTip="Zoom Out" click="{zoomOutHandler}" />
    <mx:Button id="zoomIn" label="+" width="20"
        toolTip="Zoom In" click="{zoomInHandler}" />
</mx:HBox>
```

**App.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    mx:local="*"
    creationComplete="onCompelete(event)">
    <mx:script>
        [Binable] public var scale:Number = 1.0;

        protected function onComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
           zoomButtons.zoomOutHandler = handleChangeZoomOut;
           zoomButtons.zoomInHandler = handleChangeZoomIn;
        }

        private function handleChangeZoomOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
            scale /= 2;
        }

        private function handleChangeZoomIn(event:MouseEvent):void {
            scale *= 2;
        }
    </mx:script>
    <local:ZoomButtons id="zoomButtons" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured it out. I removed the binding from the event handlers and assigned/unassigned them through a function call. This seems to work.

**ZoomButtons.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:script>
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var zoomOutHandler:Function = localZoomOutHandler;
        private var zoomInHandler:Function = localZoomInHandler;

        public function addHandlers(zoomOutHandler:Function, zoomInHandler:Function):void {
            removeHandlers();

            this.zoomOutHandler = zoomOutHandler;
            this.zoomInHandler = zoomInHandler;

            zoomOut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoomOutHandler);
            zoomIn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoomInHandler);
        }

        pubblic function removeHandlers():void {
            zoomOut.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoomOutHandler);
            zoomIn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoomInHandler);
        }

        private function localZoomOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        private function localZoomInHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    </mx:script>
    <mx:Button id="zoomOut" label="-" width="20" toolTip="Zoom Out" />
    <mx:Button id="zoomIn" label="+" width="20" toolTip="Zoom In" />
</mx:HBox>
```

**App.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    mx:local="*"
    creationComplete="onCompelete(event)">
    <mx:script>
        [Binable] public var scale:Number = 1.0;

        protected function onComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
           zoomButtons.addHandlers(handleChangeZoomOut, handleChangeZoomIn);
        }

        private function handleChangeZoomOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
            scale /= 2;
        }

        private function handleChangeZoomIn(event:MouseEvent):void {
            scale *= 2;
        }
    </mx:script>
    <local:ZoomButtons id="zoomButtons" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good thing you found a solution. However IMO the cleanest approach to do communication from a component to its container is to use events. For example dispatch some custom zoom events from ZoomButtons:

```
<fx:MetaData>
    [Event(name="zoomIn", type="flash.events.Event")]
    [Event(name="zoomOut", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:MetaData>

<mx:Button id="zoomOut" label="-" width="20"
    toolTip="Zoom Out" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('zoomOut'))" />
<mx:Button id="zoomIn" label="+" width="20"
    toolTip="Zoom In" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('zoomIn'))" />
```

And then listen for those events:

```
<local:ZoomButtons id="zoomButtons" 
    zoomIn="handleZoomIn()" 
    zoomOut="handleZoomOut()" />
```

The metadata in the custom component makes sure that the compiler understands the 'zoomIn' and 'zoomOut' event handlers written in MXML.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try this out when I get the chance.